# Capturando grupos con expresión regular no funciona

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero simplificar una expresión regular, para eliminar las partes repetitivas uso la captura de grupos y hago referencia, Pero en el siguiente caso esto no funciona. Aquí el código:

```js
let regex= /([\w\-\d]+)(\/)(\1)/g

let string1= "user-name/alias"
let string2= "user234/hello-word"

let result1= regex.test(string1)
let result2= regex.test(string2)

console.log(result1,result2)
```

El codigo anterior devovera false, es interesante que en este caso la referencia al grupo no funciona. El codigo que si funciona seria el siguiente:

```js
let regex= /([\w\-\d]+)(\/)([\w\-\d]+)/g

let string1= "user-name/alias"
let string2= "user-name/alias"

let result1= regex.test(string1)
let result2= regex.test(string2)

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

En este ultimo caso, el valor de las dos variables es la misma cadena. ¿por que al hacer el test en la ultima variable obtengo false, deberia ser true?

¿Por que la referencia al grupo no funciona?¿Que hago para que funcione?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veamos una cosa, test es un método que "modifica" el puntero, lo cambia ;cuando hablamos de standar, en cada navegador funciona de manera diferente.
para evitar que este tenga algo antes de ejecutar el test te aconsejo ocuparlo en una función "micro aplicación", donde se limpiará a cada que tu lo necesites, es un comportamiento esperado en programación pero inesperado para programadores nuevos.

```js
let regex_verificacion = (string) => {
   let regex=/([\w\-\d]+)(\/)([\w\-\d]+)/g;
  let result= regex.test(string);
  return result;
}

let string1= "user-name/alias";
let string2= "user-name/alias";

let result1= regex_verificacion(string1);
let result2= regex_verificacion(string2);


console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

cuando creamos una función, esta es limpiada y re creada (en memoria) cada ves que se llama, por eso funciona.

Comment: gracias por el aporte. La solución para el caso del test con error es correcta. Sobre el caso de hacer referencia a los grupos encontré que no puedo usar esta funcionalidad de regex para simplificar una expresión. Pues ```([\w]+)\/(\1)``` seria true para ```text/text``` por que captura la primera palabra. Por lo tanto seria false para una expresión como ```text/txet```, para este ultimo caso es necesario una expresión regular como ```([\w]+)\/([\w]+)``` para que pase el test como ```true```